# Refecltion - Dynamic class invocation

Tags: class, dynamic, reflection, factory, factory-pattern

The following is the code where if else is used. If i need to dynamically create a class. how can i do it? is Reflection used ? If so : how can i implement the same using reflection?

```
  public static Pizza getConcretePizza(String PType)
 { 
   Pizza p=null;
    if (PType.equals("Cheese")) 
      {
           p=new CheesePizza();
         //ResultIng = cp.FetchIng();
      } else if (PType.equals("Pepperoni")) 
      {
         p=new PepperoniPizza();
        // ResultIng = pp.FetchIng();
      }
      else if (PType.equals("Clam")) 
      {
          p = new CalmPizza();
          //ResultIng = cap.FetchIng();
      }
       else if (PType.equals("Veggie")) 
      {
         p= new VeggiePizza();
         // ResultIng = vp.FetchIng();
      }
       return(p); 
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried getting the answer and finally found the solution.

(INSTEAD OF THE IF _ ELSE WE NEED TO REPLACE THE FOLLWOING CODE)

```
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("PizzaTrail." + PType);
        Object instance = clazz.newInstance();
        p = (Pizza) instance;
        return (p);
```

the above code will resolve the issue of writing the if else and reflection will help calling the class dynamically.